# Char passing to other function best practice

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to pass string to second function where it fills the character array and gives the value back. In the first function I want to take the string length after second function fills it.

first step

```
 Planning to pass the character array 
 char data[10]="";
 GetData(data); // Here Iam doing memset value to data
 strlen(data);
```

second step

```
 Planning to pass the character pointer 
 char *data;
 GetData(data); // what I should do 
 strlen(data);
```

Can someone suggest which is the best practice

Comment: In your second example, GetData() takes the pointer by reference?

Comment: You've used two different C++ tags. That strongly suggests you should be using a reference to `std::string` instead.

Comment: Why not just have `GetData` return a `std::string`? Then you can do `std::string data = getData();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the character pointer should be owned by the caller, and should take care of allocation (if possible, or callee has to do that on behalf of the caller) and deallocation

```
char *data = (char *) NULL; //  should initialize to know allocated or not
```

the prototype of the call, GetData should be:

```
void GetData(char *& d); // pointer passed as reference
```

Within GetData, d shoud be allocated as:

```
d = new char[size]; //size should be appropriately decided including null terminating character
```

for example, if you wish to store a "hello" say, d should be allocated as :

```
d = new char[5+1]; // example
```

once done, in the caller, you must deallocate as:

```
if (data) delete [] data;
data = (char *) NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `std::string`, something like:

```
std::string data;
void GetData(std::string& str);
```

passing by non-`const` reference allows `GetData` to alter `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The "classic", C-compatible method in Windows (where Visual C++ is most used) is to have a function that takes the buffer size as argument, and returns the size or length of data copied. Example:

```
//Inputs:
//  buffer: [out/opt] If not null, write data here.
//  size: [in] Buffer size including null terminator, ignored if buffer is null.
//Outputs:
//  buffer: The data.
//  Return Value: Length of data written to the buffer, without null terminator.
int GetData(char *buffer, size_t bufferSize);
```

This allows calling the function with a null buffer to obtain the length to allocate, allocate the data, and call the function again.

However, it's not very C++ and it's error-prone. Passing a pointer/reference to the pointer to allocate is better from a language standpoint, but has its drawbacks when crossing a DLL boundary, where it's recommended that any data allocated by a DLL be deallocated by the same DLL (preventing the use of ordinary smart pointers).

Comment: The first line of your answer is very misleading. This is the "classic" because it is C. The Windows API is a C API. That does not mean that all code you write on Windows must (or even should) be C code.